# What is the meaning of "more likely say"?

Tags: conditional-constructions

- If I were in the place of you, I would tell him to stop crying.

Can I rewrite the above sentence in the following way?

- If I were you/If I were in the place of you, I would more likely say him to stop crying.

Is a **to** necessary before **say him to stop crying**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modal verbs *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would* always take **bare** infinitive complements: infinitives without the *to* marker. This doesn't change when you place an adverbial between the modal and its infinitive complement:

> I would say ... 
>   I would more likely say ...

There are however, other problems with your rewrite.

First, the original sentence is unidiomatic. We almost never use *of* phrases to express the genitive of personal pronouns.

> If I were in **your** place I would tell him to stop crying.

Second, you cannot simply replace *tell* with *say*, for two reasons:

- ***tell*** may be "ditransitive", taking both a Direct and an Indirect Object, but ***say*** is "monotransitive", taking only a Direct Object. With *say* the person addressed must be expressed with a *to* preposition phrase.

  > I told this to him  *or* I told him this.
  >   I said this to him  *but not* *I said him this.
- ***tell*** may take a marked infinitival clause (*to DO something*) in place of a nominal Direct Object. In this case the Indirect Object is taken to be the subject of the infinitival clause, and *tell* is understood to have the sense "command" or "instruct":

  > I told him to stop crying = *I commanded him that he must stop crying*.

  ***say*** cannot be used this way; it does not take infinitival complements.

  > *I said him to stop crying.

  And *say* does not have the sense *command*; this can be expressed only indirectly, by employing a *that* clause which includes a term which has the sense *command*:

  > I said to him that he ***must*** stop crying.

Comment: Since "I told this to him" is correct, can I say-"I said stop crying to him"? And can I use "I would more likely say"... without "to" before "say"?

Comment: @Azahar Only if *stop crying* is a direct quote: *I said "Stop crying" to him*. And see the new stuff I've just added at the end.

Comment: I (nominative) said [implied:something] (accusative) to him (dative)

Comment: @adolfgarlic W e l l ... not exactly. In English, you can't leave the object of *say* implicit. And English doesn't distinguish accusative and dative. They're useful 'handles' for people whose native language employs those cases, but they're no more relevant to English than they would be to a language which employs different cases for *he* as Indirect Object and *he* as the oblique of the pronoun corresponding to *to*.

Comment: @StoneyB I can think of a few counterexamples, like "I couldn't say" or "it goes without saying", but in that context it does sound weird.

Comment: @MiloPrice Yes, I should be a shade less absolute! ... But those are both things that would only occur as responses with the implicit object already explicit in the immediately preceding discourse.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we can't use "say" without a preposition "to" if we want to mention an addressee:

> "I'm your cousin. We've never met before." - she said to me.

But:

> "I'm your cousin. We've never met before." - she told me.

If we use "tell" and indirect speech, "to" will be necessary. If we use say, we should use direct speech and refrain from using "to". So your example will look like this:

> If I were you, I would more likely tell him to stop crying.
>
> If I were you, I would more likely say to him: "Stop crying".

You can find more information on the usage of say/tell for example [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/say-or-tell).

Answer (score 2):

If I may, a better variation of the sentence would be :

> If I were you, I would **probably** tell him to stop crying.

Adding a *'to'* before *'say him to stop crying'* isn't right. And I would use *'tell'* instead of *'say'*, but that's up to you.

Comment: That has the most natural flow I believe.